# Scan image file or disk for pattern and return its location

Tags: linux, disk-image, block-device

Say I have a block device or an image file. And say I also have a sequence of bytes or a string or some search pattern. How can I get the positions of the occurrences of such a pattern or string? Are there any tools for that?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to use

```
grep -aob "string to find" /dev/blockdev
```

- the "a" switch treats the file as text, so it displays the output, the "o" switch limits the output to the offset and string you are searching for so you don't get binary garbage and the "b" switch tells it to print the byte offset as well.

Comment: **grep works by lines**. If grep encounters several Gigabytes without a newline byte the system memory will be full. **This is definitely not the right command**. At least not for a block device.

Answer (score 0):

This question has multiple answers, depending on what  you wish to search for exactly.

If you wish to find all *character strings* inside a binary file, then the command is **strings**: from [the Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings),

> **strings(1)**
>
> **Name**
>
> **strings** - print the strings of printable characters in files.
>
> .... For each file given, GNU **strings** prints the printable character sequences that are at least 4 characters long (or the number given with the options below) and are followed by an unprintable character. By default, it only prints the strings from the initialized and loaded sections of object files; for other types of files, it prints the strings from the whole file.

If you are instead interested in searching a binary file for a **binary string**, you can use [bgrep](https://bgrep.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (not in the repos, AFAIK):

> bgrep is a utility for searching for occurrences of binary strings within binary files. As its name suggests, its interface and design is modeled after the ubiquitous “grep” command, used to search for occurrences of text patterns in text files.

Alternatively, you can use the following ruse:

```
cat YourFile | hexdump -C | grep YourPattern
```

This uses `hexdump`: again [from the Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump),

> **hexdump(1)**
>
> **Name**
>
> **hexdump** - ascii, decimal, hexadecimal, octal dump

I use the convenient `-C` format:

> **-C** Canonical hex+ASCII display. Display the input offset in hexadecimal, followed by sixteen space-separated, two column, hexadecimal bytes, followed by the same sixteen bytes in %_p format enclosed in ''|'' characters.

while some people prefer the `-c` format:

> **-c** One-byte character display. Display the input offset in hexadecimal, followed by sixteen space-separated, three column, space-filled, characters of input data per line.